Дублирование вывода fetchAll с пустыми полями
Потратив пол дня, я нашёл странный баг, который выводит одну и ту же запись 2 раза если поле пустое.
class SearchPeople{
    private $dsn = 'sqlsrv:Server=test\sql;Database=test;';
    private $user = 'test';
    private $password = 'test';
    private $options  = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC];
    private $con;
    public function __construct(){
        try {
            $this->con=new PDO($this->dsn, $this->user, $this->password, $this->options);                
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            var_dump($e);
        }        
    }
    public function searchPeople(){                                                                              
        $sql="SELECT distinct id,sName,Name,pName,dateMan,typeDoc,serDoc,numDoc,dateDoc,contact FROM people WHERE sName = ? 
            AND Name = ? AND dateMan = ? AND typeDoc = ? AND numDoc = ? AND dateDoc = ?  AND (pName = ? OR pName IS NULL)  
            AND (serDoc = ? OR serDoc IS NULL)";
        $query = $this->con->prepare($sql);
        $tr=['testov', 'test', '10.12.2010', '24', '555333', '01.04.2011','',''];
        $query->execute($tr);
        $result=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                
        return $result;
    }
}
    $db=new SearchPeople();    
    $result=$db->searchPeople();    
    var_dump($result);  

Версия PHP 8.3.2, база MSSQL(в базе этот же запрос выводит одну запись)
Кто знает в чём причина и как исправить такое поведение?
P.S.Добавляю скриншоты того что выполняю;
Запрос в базе(только что создал запись(даже убрал distinct для наглядности)

Сам код, который выполняю

Вывод


1.попробуйте подумать, что означает условие pName = ? OR pName IS NULL. Это объяснит вам, почему   ваш запрос запрос находит записи, в которых  у pName и serDoc  в базе NULL. 2. попробуйте посмотреть внимательнее, как на самом деле выглядит условие, если делать трюк, который вы попытались использовать. 3. Почему возвращает одну и ту же запись, я затрудняюсь сказать. Скорее всего это две разных. Если вы считаете, что одна, то сделайте рабочий пример на https://phpize.online/ и дайте на него сылку


Условие (pName = ? OR pName IS NULL) означает что нужно выбрать запись или с пустым полем или со значением NULL в зависимости от того что будет в базе но строка так же должна соответствовать полям перечисленным через 'AND' 2. Я выполнял этот запрос в своей базе, он отрабатывает корректно. В этой таблице на поле id висит первичный ключ, соответственно все записи уникальные если в моём условии используется distinct. 3. Две одинаковых записи, так как поле id с одним и тем же значением(а как я говорил ранее, оно в таблице уникальное.


На счёт примера. Я постарался воспроизвести по вашей ссылке структуру базы и кода, но данная ситуация не воспроизводится. Возможно это связано с какими то другими изменениями или версией ПО, но данный скрипт одинаково работает на 2х версиях php 8.2.3 и 7.3 установленных на моём пк. Может есть какие то настройки в Apache, которые влияют на выполнение кода.

Apache-то здесь при чём?

Я не пойму, у вас в поле pName может быть всего два значения - пустая строка и null? Иначе ваше условие будет работать не так. Оно или найдет поле, значение которого равно переданному значению, или, если не найдет, то вернет все строки, в которых в этом поле записано null.

В любом случае, от себя PDO ничего не добавляет. Хотя стоп. Покажите мне это ваше "два раза". сдается, мне, объяснение куда глупее, чем кажется.

Да, Apache здесь точно не причём, так как данный код в консоли возвращает то же самое. Поле pName  в данном случае null, но оно так же может быть пустым(на самом деле это максимально обрезанный код, полный код смотрит если поле не пустое, то вместо двух проверок будет только одна ( {$field} = ?)). Добавил скрины в пост и привёл код в соответствии со скрином. К сожалению не получается воспроизвести этот код на той площадке куда вы мне дали ссылку.

Да, похоже на баг. Но без воспроизводящего кода вы даже баг-репорт сделать не сможете.

В общем не знаю что это за глюк и  из-за чего конкретно он происходит, но исчезновение двойного вывода исправляется непосредственной подстановкой в код запроса пустых кавычек без подстановки пустого значения в подготовленный запрос, т.е.:
  //конструкцию 
$sql="SELECT id,sName,Name,pName,dateMan,typeDoc,serDoc,numDoc,dateDoc,contact FROM people WHERE sName = ? 
            AND Name = ? AND dateMan = ? AND typeDoc = ? AND numDoc = ? AND dateDoc = ?  AND (pName = ? OR pName IS NULL)  
            AND (serDoc = ? OR serDoc IS NULL)";
        $query = $this->con->prepare($sql);
        $tr=['testov', 'test', '10.12.2010', '24', '555333', '01.04.2011','',''];
//заменяем на 
$sql="SELECT id,sName,Name,pName,dateMan,typeDoc,serDoc,numDoc,dateDoc,contact FROM people WHERE sName = ? 
            AND Name = ? AND dateMan = ? AND typeDoc = ? AND numDoc = ? AND dateDoc = ?  AND (pName = '' OR pName IS NULL)  
            AND (serDoc = '' OR serDoc IS NULL)";
        $query = $this->con->prepare($sql);
        $tr=['testov', 'test', '10.12.2010', '24', '555333', '01.04.2011'];

Может кому то будет полезно
